# Add average line to stacked column chart

Tags: powerbi, dax

Is there a workaround to add an average line to a stacked column chart?

Whenever I add the average measure to the line value it displays it as a moving average, and it only works if I have a clustered chart.

Is there some other way to do this using DAX or is it currently impossible in Power Bi?

Note: The average should be overall rather than an average for each year/time period

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Calculate() and All() will help as is instructed here:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Clustered-column-average-total/m-p/905575